# TypeInitializationException when accessing App.Config connection string

Tags: c#, connection-string, app-config

I created a static utility class to simplify access to the db and  am getting the following exception when i run my code "TypeInitializationException".

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="vistConnectionString" connectionString="XXXXX"/>
</connectionStrings>


static class DBUtility
{
    private static string dbConnection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["vistConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

    public static string DbConnection
    {
        get { return dbConnection; }
    }  
}
```

If i call the static property then I recieve a TypeInitializationException exception

```
string s = DBUtility.DbConnection; // this line throws the exception
```

The message from the exception is

```
Message=The type initializer for 'VIServiceToolServiceLibrary.Database.DBUtility' threw an exception.
```

Comment: I guess there is an error with this line `private static string dbConnection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["vistConnectionString"].ConnectionString`

Comment: The coonection string was okay because it was working when hard coded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use code below for connection

```
var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["vistConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
try { con.Open(); }
```